# iOS Simulator CPU load

Tags: ios, performance, ios-simulator

When looking at the performance of an app on the simulator, I can see the CPU load.

Is the CPU figure a simulated load on a real device, or is it the load on the Mac's CPU from running the simulator?

I understand that neither would tell me much about the real performance on device, and I do regularly test on device. But I was wondering if anyone know, or if there's any information about what this number means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the iOS simulator is not replicating an iOS device in terms of performance. The numbers are simply the load on the Mac's CPU and are not a good indicator of performance on a real ARM iOS device.

The simulator numbers may be ok for comparing relative performance of some operations, but you should be sure to test on device, especially when using other hardware features such as the GPU.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I agree that it shouldn't be used as a guide for programming. I was interested to see what it told me about how the simulator is implemented. Just as a curiosity thing. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Ian, you could also use Instruments to test on the device through XCode to get actual figures and whatnot.